# Typescript ругается на свойство response от error в функции createAsyncThunk от redux-toolkit

Tags: reactjs, typescript, redux

Что нужно сделать, что бы не было ругани на свойство? Вроде ж кагбэ такого быть не должно, но есть...

> ESLint: Unsafe member access .response on an any
> value.(@typescript-eslint/no-unsafe-member-access)

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

```
export const actionFetchDataUser = createAsyncThunk(
  'data/user',
  async (formVal: TformVal, { rejectWithValue }) => {
    try {
      const GoogleAuth = window.gapi.auth2.getAuthInstance();
      const profileMail = await GoogleAuth.signIn({
        scope: 'profile email',
      });
      const googleEmail = profileMail.getBasicProfile().getEmail();
      if (googleEmail !== formVal.email) {
        throw Error('There is NO email');
      }
      return {
        name: profileMail.getBasicProfile().getName(),
        ava: profileMail.getBasicProfile().getImageUrl(),
      };
    } catch (err) {
     // Here is problem
      if (!err.response) {
        throw err;
      }
      return rejectWithValue(err);
    }
  },
);
```

Comment: и какой текст ошибки?

Comment: в общем то это не важно, правильно будет так: `if (err && 'response' in err)` https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?#code/GYVwdgxgLglg9mABMAFAQwPwC5EG9EBGOaYAnogL4CUeAsAFCJOIzCLqIBkniA5AbxZI0NXA2YTEAeimIAtABo545hUQBTADYBndXUaSmM+UpVMKDCkA

Comment: Так можно выйти из ситуации частично, потому что return rejectWithValue(err); здесь нужно пробросить ошибки в таком виде return rejectWithValue(err.response).Если пробросить все err, то в createSlice эти проблемы с типизацией будут преследовать

Comment: _____________чо?

Comment: ESLint: Unsafe member access .response on an any value.(@typescript-eslint/no-unsafe-member-access)

Comment: 1) пиши как я говорю, не вникай, потом разберёшься 2) на будущее: eslint и язык ts - разные вещи, указывай его в вопросе

Comment: _____________хз

Comment: rly. `if (err && 'response' in err) rejectWithValue(err) else throw err;`

Comment: Мне нужно вытянуть текст с ошибки и отобразить чё за хЭ произошло, просто прокинуть ошибку не варик

Comment: На свойства типа message и name тоже ругается

Comment: привет типизация - `err` может быть `undefined` т.к. имеет тип `any` а у `undefined` не может быть `response`;;;`console.log(undefined.response)` - "Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'response' of undefined"

Comment: По-идее в блоке catch err всегда будет иметь какое-то значение, то есть undefined никогда быть не должно

Comment: Да, по идее в js, но тс пофигу у него стоит any

Comment: `function q() { throw undefined; }
try { q() } catch (e) { console.error('err', e, typeof e) }`

Comment: и, судя по тесту, не напрасно

Comment: Ну если пробросить undefined, тогда undefined будет в catch

Comment: Странно, что здесь не ругается
https://codesandbox.io/s/react-redux-toolkit-jqugh?file=/src/redux/slice.ts

Answer (score 0):

Один хороший человек порекомендовал такой способ решения

```
catch (err) {
      const hasErrResponse = (err as { response: { [key: string]: string } }).response;
      if (!hasErrResponse) {
        throw err;
      }
      return rejectWithValue(hasErrResponse);
    }
```

Comment: ______избыточно

Comment: С использованием ts почти всегда код выглядит избыточно :D. Ну и как бы там ни было это рабочий вариант и пока единственный. Да и я написал так для наглядности, у себя сократил до const hasErrResponse = (err as TerrObjResponse).response;

Answer (score 0):

Если я правильно понимаю, линтер сигнализирует о том, что свойство `response` может отсутствовать в `err`. В таком случае можно использовать [оператор опциональной последовательности](https://developer.mozilla.org/ru/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Optional_chaining). `if (!err?.response) {`. Если у `err` не будет свойства `response`, то вернётся `undefined`.

Второй вариант - расширить тип для err таким образом, чтобы он определял наличие свойства `response`.

Comment: Хорошо было бы второй вариант расписать. Это всё равно, что написать, ну надо что-то сделать с err и response.